# Authorization failed for access token request using implicit and client-credentials flow in oppeniddict

Tags: asp.net-core, jwt, asp.net-identity, openiddict

I have been able to successfully handle the authentication while using the `implicit flow` but when i added the new flow `client-credentials` there is the error, while making the call for the token.

Making the token call:

```
var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "http://localhost:54783/connect/token");
request.Content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    ["grant_type"] = "client_credentials",
    ["client_id"] = "console",
    ["client_secret"] = "388D45FA-B36B-4988-BA59-B187D329C207"
});
var response = await client.SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseContentRead);
response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
var payload = JObject.Parse(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
```

While tracing to the response log i found that the authorization server is trying to authenticate the `request for token access`.

As seen on my log i get the error as:

```
2019-12-24 09:55:13.864 +05:45 [Information] The token request was successfully validated.
2019-12-24 09:55:14.149 +05:45 [Information] Authorization failed for user: null.
2019-12-24 09:55:14.154 +05:45 [Information] Authorization failed for the request at filter '"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Authorization.AuthorizeFilter"'.
2019-12-24 09:55:14.168 +05:45 [Information] Executing ChallengeResult with authentication schemes (["Bearer", "Identity.Application"]).
2019-12-24 09:55:14.177 +05:45 [Information] AuthenticationScheme: "Bearer" was challenged.
2019-12-24 09:55:14.184 +05:45 [Information] AuthenticationScheme: "Identity.Application" was challenged.
2019-12-24 09:55:14.192 +05:45 [Information] Executed action "AWS.BackOffice.Controllers.TokenController.Exchange (AWS.BackOffice)" in 57.8699ms
2019-12-24 09:55:14.203 +05:45 [Information] Request finished in 763.4318ms 302 
2019-12-24 09:55:14.210 +05:45 [Information] Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:54783/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2Fconnect%2Ftoken  
2019-12-24 09:55:14.320 +05:45 [Information] Executing action method "AWS.BackOffice.Controllers.AccountController.Login (AWS.BackOffice)" with arguments (["/connect/token"]) - ModelState is Valid
2019-12-24 09:55:18.521 +05:45 [Information] Executing ViewResult, running view at path "/Views/Account/Login.cshtml".
2019-12-24 09:55:19.719 +05:45 [Information] Executed action "AWS.BackOffice.Controllers.AccountController.Login (AWS.BackOffice)" in 5455.3915ms
2019-12-24 09:55:19.724 +05:45 [Information] Request finished in 5514.963ms 200 text/html; charset=utf-8
```

Startup.cs - **ConfigureServices**

```
services.AddMvc().AddJsonOptions(options =>
{
    options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
});


var connectionString = Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
services.AddDbContext<DbContext>(options =>
{
    // Configure the context to use Microsoft SQL Server.
    options.UseSqlServer(connectionString);
    options.UseOpenIddict<Guid>();
});

services.AddIdentity<User, Role>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<DbContext>()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options =>
{
    options.ClaimsIdentity.UserNameClaimType = OpenIdConnectConstants.Claims.Name;
    options.ClaimsIdentity.UserIdClaimType = OpenIdConnectConstants.Claims.Subject;
    options.ClaimsIdentity.RoleClaimType = OpenIdConnectConstants.Claims.Role;
});

services.AddOpenIddict().AddCore(options =>
    {
        options.UseEntityFrameworkCore()
               .UseDbContext<DbContext>()
               .ReplaceDefaultEntities<Guid>();

    }).AddServer(options =>
    {
        options.UseMvc();
        options.EnableAuthorizationEndpoint("/connect/authorize")
                 .EnableLogoutEndpoint("/connect/logout")
                 .EnableIntrospectionEndpoint("/connect/introspect")
                 .EnableUserinfoEndpoint("/api/userinfo")
                 .EnableTokenEndpoint("/connect/token");


        options.RegisterScopes(OpenIdConnectConstants.Scopes.Email,
                               OpenIdConnectConstants.Scopes.Profile,
                               OpenIddictConstants.Scopes.Roles);


        options.AddEphemeralSigningKey();

        options.AllowClientCredentialsFlow();
        options.AllowImplicitFlow();

        options.DisableHttpsRequirement();
        //options.AddDevelopmentSigningCertificate();
        options.UseJsonWebTokens();
    });//.AddValidation();



services.AddMvc(config =>
{
    var defaultPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder(new[] { JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme })
                     .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                     .Build();
    config.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(defaultPolicy));
});


JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap.Clear();
JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultOutboundClaimTypeMap.Clear();

services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OAuthValidationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;

})
.AddJwtBearer(options =>
{
    options.Authority = Configuration["SettingsConfig:AuthUrl"];
    options.Audience = "resource-server-1";
    options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        NameClaimType = OpenIdConnectConstants.Claims.Subject,
        RoleClaimType = OpenIdConnectConstants.Claims.Role
    };
});

var builder = services.AddIdentityCore<User>(o =>
{
    o.Password.RequireDigit = false;
    o.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
    o.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
    o.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
    o.Password.RequiredLength = 6;
});
services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy",
        b => b.AllowAnyOrigin()
            .AllowAnyMethod()
            .AllowAnyHeader()
            .Build());
});
services.AddTransient<UserManager<User>>();
.............
```

What i think is i may be missing some configuration on the `JWTBearer` but couldn't find what could be causing the error.

Also i have the auuthorization and resource server in the same project.

Comment: Is your `Exchange` action decorated with `[Authorize]`? If so, remove that to get rid of the bogus redirects.

Comment: no it was not decorated with `[Authorize]` but i added `[AllowAnonymous]` and that works! but i have no `[Authorize]` attribute in controller but it was redirecting automatically.

Comment: Oh yeah, that's because you added it at the global level: `config.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(defaultPolicy))`.